# How should I prepare the data for Lightgbm categorical_features?

Tags: python, categorical-data, lightgbm

The [categorical_feature](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#categorical_feature) of the lightgbm library states that:

- Note: all values will be cast to int32

But also that:

- Note: all values should be less than Int32.MaxValue (2147483647)
- Note: using large values could be memory consuming. Tree decision rule works best when categorical features are presented by consecutive integers starting from zero

What are the values that should be less than int32.MaxValue (and shouldn't be large), the ones casted by Lgbm (which means I can just give the data I have regardless if they're large) or the ones I'm giving to the model as categorical_features?

I've tried giving large values, negative values and even values greater than Int32.MaxValue and the lightgbm LGBMRegressor still works so I'm not sure why the notes concerning the values are there.

Answer (score 0):

Data in `categorical_features` columns should be in range of 0~Int32.MaxValue (2147483647).

So your data has less thanInt32.MaxValue (2147483647) categories. You need to do a mapping your data to range of 0~2147483647 before loading into dataset. Make sure after mapping, no mapped value conflict. **Keep the mapping algorithm, it should be also used in prediction.**